# How to communicate between two app.config files?

Tags: c#, windows-services, settings, app-config, multi-user

i have two projects in one solution

1)Windows Application(Project1)
2)Windows Service(Project2)

it is a multi-user application for an organisation.

Windows Service is installed in Server and Windows application is installed in Client Computers.

Now i am designing a Settings Form for windows application. for this i am using

```
Project1-->Properties-->Settings-->
```

after adding the settings the data is stored in **Project1 app.config** file like this

```
<userSettings>
<Project1._1.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="backColor" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Yellow</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="forecolor" serializeAs="String">
    <value>ControlText</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="font" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="datetime" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="formbackground" serializeAs="String">
    <value>GradientActiveCaption</value>
  </setting>
</Project1._1.Properties.Settings>
```

the above one will work for single client(100%). But now this is a multi-user application. 
**For this if i use the above code i need to change in every client application**.
i.e., not good for this i want an idea.

i have a doubt why can i save the Settings data in Project2, from this i want to access the setting information, is it possible.

If anybody have any better idea.Please give an answer.

Comment: It's not clear, what's your problem. First of all, settings are stored in settings file, which is not the same as app.config file. Settings has a scope (machine or user), but this only determines, which settings file will be used to store particular settings item (settings file, shared by every user, or individual settings file per user). Note, that *settings* differs from *configuration*. Settings are options, that could be changed by user. Configuration is a set of options, that could be changed by admin (directly or indirectly, e.g. during the installation process).

Comment: @Dennis i want that settings file should be common for every USER

Comment: Looks like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.clientservices.providers.clientsettingsprovider.aspx is what your want.

Comment: hi @Dennis the above links are belongs to asp.net not windows